# Creating similar form for Appendix as the Chapter structure

Tags: chapters, appendix, chapterbib

I want my appendices to follow the same form as my chapters, that is, I want the Appendix so say for example "Appendix A" in the same form as my chapters. My chapters looks like this:

[image]

Which, I'm pretty sure follows from the following line of codes:

```
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{\chaptername\ \thechapter.\ #1}{}}
```

I was just wondering if any of you LaTeX-gurus see a quick way of handling this? I have looked it up, but it doesn't look like many out there use the same format for the Appendices as I want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this?

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage[Lenny]{fncychap}
\usepackage{appendix}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{\chaptername\ \thechapter.\ #1}{}}

\begin{document}
\chapter{A}
\begin{appendices} 

  \chapter{Title of this appendix}\label{apx:f}

  \section{An appendix section}

\end{appendices}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much! Works perfectly, I really appreciate your help.

Comment: @hakver29, you are welcome.